# Why does ServiceStack OrmLite crash with null exception when I add OrmLite.Firebird?

Tags: c#, servicestack, visual-studio-2015, firebird

I'm evaluating ServiceStack and OrmLite and wanted to try it with a Firebird database. Using the ServiceStack.Northwind demo as a starting place, when I add the ServiceStack.OrmLite.Firebird reference to the C# assembly references, the app begins to crash at startup with a null error at assembly load time:

The line of code that it happens at in Global.asax.cs:

```
 public class AppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        public AppHost() : base("Northwind Web Services", typeof(CustomersService).Assembly) {}   // <-- Here!
```

The exception:

```
System.TypeLoadException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233054
  Message=Method 'Execute' in type 'ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController' from assembly 'ServiceStack, Version=4.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
  Source=ServiceStack
  TypeName=ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController
  StackTrace:
       at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost..ctor(String serviceName, Assembly[] assembliesWithServices)
       at ServiceStack.AppHostBase..ctor(String serviceName, Assembly[] assembliesWithServices)
       at ServiceStack.Northwind.AppHost..ctor() in C:\dev\ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.Northwind\ServiceStack.Northwind\Global.asax.cs:line 13
       at ServiceStack.Northwind.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\dev\ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.Northwind\ServiceStack.Northwind\Global.asax.cs:line 31
  InnerException:
```

The demo source is here: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Northwind
(Only change necessary is to run `Install-Package ServiceStack.OrmLite.Firebird` from package manager console.)

Here's the package manager console session:

```
Package Manager Console Host Version 3.1.1.0

Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.OrmLite.Firebird
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.Firebird.4.0.44' with respect to project 'ServiceStack.Northwind', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.Firebird.4.0.44' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.Firebird.4.0.44'
Resolved actions to install package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.Firebird.4.0.44'
Removed package 'ServiceStack.Common.4.0.11' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'ServiceStack.Common.4.0.11' from ServiceStack.Northwind
Removed package 'ServiceStack.Interfaces.4.0.11' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'ServiceStack.Interfaces.4.0.11' from ServiceStack.Northwind
Removed package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.4.0.11' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.4.0.11' from ServiceStack.Northwind
Removed package 'ServiceStack.Text.4.0.11' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'ServiceStack.Text.4.0.11' from ServiceStack.Northwind
Adding package 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.4.7.0' to folder 'C:\dev\ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.Northwind\packages'
Added package 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.4.7.0' to folder 'C:\dev\ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.Northwind\packages'
Added package 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.4.7.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient 4.7.0' to ServiceStack.Northwind
Adding package 'ServiceStack.Interfaces.4.0.44' to folder 'C:\dev\ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.Northwind\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Interfaces.4.0.44' to folder 'C:\dev\ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.Northwind\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Interfaces.4.0.44' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.Interfaces 4.0.44' to ServiceStack.Northwind
Adding package 'ServiceStack.Text.4.0.44' to folder 'C:\dev\ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.Northwind\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Text.4.0.44' to folder 'C:\dev\ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.Northwind\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Text.4.0.44' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.Text 4.0.44' to ServiceStack.Northwind
Adding package 'ServiceStack.Common.4.0.44' to folder 'C:\dev\ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.Northwind\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Common.4.0.44' to folder 'C:\dev\ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.Northwind\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Common.4.0.44' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.Common 4.0.44' to ServiceStack.Northwind
Adding package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.4.0.44' to folder 'C:\dev\ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.Northwind\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.4.0.44' to folder 'C:\dev\ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.Northwind\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.4.0.44' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.OrmLite 4.0.44' to ServiceStack.Northwind
Adding package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.Firebird.4.0.44' to folder 'C:\dev\ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.Northwind\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.Firebird.4.0.44' to folder 'C:\dev\ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.Northwind\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.Firebird.4.0.44' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.Firebird 4.0.44' to ServiceStack.Northwind
PM>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mix and match different versions of ServiceStack libraries together. This error suggests that it's still trying to load older v4.0.11 of ServiceStack:

> Message=Method 'Execute' in type
>   'ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController' from assembly 'ServiceStack,
>   Version=4.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have
>   an implementation.

I'd recommend instead cloning the [ServiceStackApps/Northwind](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Northwind) repository which just includes a stand-alone copy Northwind project as-is deployed on the  [northwind.servicestack.net](http://northwind.servicestack.net/) Live Demo website and which already references the latest stable v4.0.44 libraries which will make it easier to modify without any NuGet package upgrade issues.

Comment: I used `Update-Package -Reinstall ServiceStack.Interfaces` on all to get rid of the persistent reference to 4.0.11 on each of the sub-assemblies within my demo solution, one by one, and this has the nice effect of modifying the .csproj and the packages.config, and neatly repairing the version conflict.    ServiceStack is really awesome by the way.